# How to recrusive replace from Linux Shell "oldtext" with "new/text"?

Tags: linux, replace

How can I replace in Linux old string: www.domain.com with new string: 192.168.1.100/public_html

I supouse I would use sed function:

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

Something like this:

```
sed -i 's/www.domain.com/192.168.1.100/public_html/g' file.txt
```

My Problem is "/" in new string, how to include this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either escape `/` like that:

```
sed -i 's/www.domain.com/192.168.1.100\/public_html/g' file.txt
```

Or choose a different delimiter, for example `,`:

```
sed -i 's,www.domain.com,192.168.1.100/public_html,g' file.txt
```